# How to detect and eliminate outliers from a changing dataset

Tags: python, numpy, dataset, computer-vision, outliers

I have a dataset which contains pixel values of a certain object by frame. My code can detect the object accurately most of the time; yet, there are negatives.

I plotted first 600 values (x-axis: frame number, y-axis: pixel location of object). In first image, you can see raw data; in second image, you can see correct path.

I already tried mean and median-filtering with different parameters, I couldn't get anything useful. Is there any way/algorithm to replace outliers with correct values?

[image: dataset]
[image: annotated dataset]

Comment: What is causing the location to change as you advance along the x-axis? Surely that is a dependent variable that would need to be accommodated in any model used to fit the data?

Comment: @ShawnMehan location of the object that I track is moving along x-axis. It's because Im analyzing a video taken from a UAV.

Comment: I think you'll be able to get pretty close with some sort of piecewise linear regression. I think the human eye has it "easy" to pick up the correct path since the long straight lines stand off from the rest of the data. If you post the actual data I might be able to give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

[RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC) is a technique to ignore outliers and select only inliers for any computation.

Since this case does not have a mathematical function to fit in the data, you cannot apply RANSAC directly.

But, as a work around, by looking into the data graph, you can try to fit a line in every 20 frames of data, and remove all outliers at each interval. This might help to ignore and reduce the effect of total outliers.